# до поры до времени

Tags: значения, выбор-слова

How would you typically translate до поры до времени, and how is it different from a less idiomatic phrase like в данное время?

Comment: "For the time being " is the closest meaning. as well as "now" for the second phrase.

Comment: I'd interpret the literal meaning of the phrase as '**until the time comes for it to change**'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**до поры до времени** - for the time being; temporarily

**в данное время** - at this/present moment; presently; currently

The 1st adverb underscores transient nature of an event or a state, the 2nd one is neutral in this respect, just describing the current state, which may or may not be bound to change.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a few translations loosely based on [these reverso examples](http://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%B4%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B+%D0%B4%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8):

- Роллинг с его́ миллиа́рдами ну́жен мне **до поры́ до вре́мени**.
  I need Rolling and his billions **only for so long**.
- И всё бы́ло хорошо́... **до поры́ до вре́мени**.
  And it worked... **for a while**.
- Все они таки́е, **до поры́ до вре́мени**.
  They all are, **until they aren't anymore**.

Comment: I'm familiar with Reverso; Ive seen all of those. It's not a great help for getting into the nuances, though.

Comment: That's why I translated the above examples myself or at least validated Reverso translations.

Answer (score 1):

> ...and how is it different from a less idiomatic phrase like в данное
>   время?

This idiom emphasizes that the situation cannot continue indefinitely. And the finale can have critical consequences.

Роллинг с его миллиардами нужен мне до поры до времени

At some point, I will not need Rolling and the fate of Rolling will be tragical

Comment: That's really interesting. So there's an element of suspense built into this phrase? That makes sense, because it is so often translated with an ellipsis ahead of it.

Comment: @spoko this depends on the context, you legitimately can say *Я здесь работаю до поры до времени. Как только я найду что-нибудь получше, меня отсюда как ветром сдует* - *I only work here for the time being. As soon as I find a better job I will be gone.* which of course is no tragic consequence either for the employer or the speaker

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Also thanks for the phrase как ветром сдует—hadn't seen that one before.

Comment: @spoko sure....